# Help for Simple Counting Problem

Tags: combinatorics

> Suppose that a large pack of Haribo gummi bears can have anywhere
> between 30 and 50 gummi bears. There are 5 delicious flavors:
> pineapple (clear), raspberry (red), orange (orange), strawberry
> (green, mysteriously), and lemon (yellow). There are 0 non-delicious
> flavors. How many possibilities are there for the composition of such
> a pack of gummi bears? You can leave your answer in terms of a couple
> binomial coecients, but not a sum of lots of binomial coecients.

Here is my thinking. I wanted to figure out how to solve this with 30 gummy bears. Here's my thinking, for each gummy, we have 5 choices for what it's flavor should be, and since we have 30 gummies, it's $5^{30}$. But order doesn't matter, so we divide by 30!.

So, to generalize this, we have $\sum_{30}^{50}\frac{5^i}{i!}$.

Is this the correct thinking?

Comment: This is not correct because when you have multiples of the same kind of gummy bear (which you will) the denominator is smaller.  It depends on the number of each color.

Comment: See [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: @RossMillikan I see. Let's say we have 30 gummies, and my flavor breakdown is 5 pineapple, 6 raspberry, 7 orange, 8 strawberry, 4  lemon. Then, is it $\frac{5^{30}}{(5!6!7!8!4!)(5!)}$? I feel like I'm missing a few terms in the denominator: I adjusted for overcounting for order within each flavor and the order of the flavors but I feel like I need to adjust for more things. Of course, I won't be approaching the problem this way anymore, I decided to use stars and bars, but I'm curious about how to adjust for overcounting for the case I mentioned above

Comment: Note... $5^{30}$ has only $5$ as a prime factor yet your proposed denominators have factors of $2,3,7$ and possibly other primes different than $5$.  The result can not possibly be an integer and as such can not possibly be the answer to a counting problem.

Comment: Also seen on quora, https://www.quora.com/A-pack-of-gummy-bears-can-be-30-to-50-There-are-5-flavors-How-many-possibilities-are-there-for-the-composition-of-such-a-pack-of-gummy-bears

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, your proposed approach involves numbers which are not integers and as such are not answers to counting problems.

The correct approach involves [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Let $x_1$ be the number of pineapple bears, $x_2$ the number of raspberry bears, and so on...  Let $x_6$ be the number of bears missing from a "full" pack.

We have the diophantine system:

$$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=50\\0\leq x_i\text{   for all i}\\0\leq x_6\leq 20\end{cases}$$

If we were to ignore the upper bound on $x_6$ this is a standard problem which can be solved via stars and bars and will have a total number of solutions equal to $\binom{50+6-1}{6-1}$.

Of these, some number are invalid because $x_6$ was too large, i.e. that $21\leq x_6$.  Those can be counted by first making a change of variable, letting $x_6-21=y$ giving the equivalent system:

$$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+y = 29\\0\leq x_i~\text{for all i}\\0\leq y\end{cases}$$

This has a number of solutions $\binom{29+6-1}{6-1}$.  Removing the bad from the good and simplifying, this gives a final total of:

$$\binom{55}{5}-\binom{34}{5} = 3200505$$